# Is it possible to download in parallel with wget?

Tags: wget

I am downloading a bunch of files from a list, using `wget`, with this

```
wget -nc --input-file=list
```

The problem with this method is that it downloads files in sequence and takes a long time.

I know I can break the file into multiple smaller files and fire manually several commands. I ask if it is possible to do it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible with `wget`.

You might try `aria2c --input-file`, which is much more advanced a command line program for downloading via HTTP.

> I know I can break the file into multiple smaller files and fire manually several commands. I ask if it is possible to do it automatically.

Don't do that manually. That's what [GNU `parallel`](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel.html#tutorial) is for.